# Probaility of Drawing Characters in Game Apps

Tags: probability

I am newbie of stack exchange.

Currently, I am playing a game and wondering how much probability I can get good characters during the draws.

The chance of getting a high rank character for each draw is 3%.

What is the probability that I can get 3 or more high rank characters in 10 draws ?

Thanks

Comment: If you draw one characters, you cannot draw it again? i.e after the first character is drawn there are only 9 characters to be drawn from?

Comment: I can draw again.

Comment: Maybe rephrase like that, each single draw to get the high rank character must be 3% chance. What is the chance I can get 3 or more high rank character in 10 attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use the binomial distribution to solve this.

You want to draw 3 or more high rank characters out of 10 draws, this is the same as asking what is the probability of drawing none, one or two high ranking characters.

If you are familiar with probability theory, the random variable is $Bin(10,0.03)$

Therefore:

Not drawing high ranking characters at all: $0.97^{10} =\sim 0.737$

Drawing exactly one high ranking character: $10*0.03*0.97^9 = \sim 0.228$

Drawing two high ranking characters: $\binom{10}{2} 0.03^2*0.97^8 =\sim 0.031$

Therefore the probability of drawing at least three high ranking characters:

$$1-0.737-0.228-0.031 = \frac{1}{250}$$

Comment: simple and nice answer !

Comment: @hosting24 thanks :)